# Splitting Java string where ideal delimiter exist before the split location

Tags: java, regex

I'm not sure how I can use the Java String.split() function to separate the following string into 2 separate strings. I want to split them such that each string starts with "{"cluster...".

I can't just use comma as a delimiter since commas exist in places before the location I want to split at.

I could technically split it at the literal "},", and then re-add "}" to the leading string, but I was wondering if there's a less messy way.

*{"cluster":"default","name":"1.2.3.4","queryEndpoint":"http://1.2.13.4:809/query/service","adminEndpoint":"http://1.2.3.4:809/admin","options":null},{"cluster":"default","name":"110.258.30.54","queryEndpoint":"http://110.258.30.54:809/query/service","adminEndpoint":"http://110.258.30.54:809/admin","options":null}*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a JSON parser to parse JSON. Don't manipulate them with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zero-width positive lookbehind pattern.

```
    String[] t = s.split("(?<=}),");
```

See [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 3):

### Positive lookbehind

This is a good example to use regex lookarounds.

You could use a positive lookbehind as [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029) showed in his answer by using this regex:

```
(?<=}),
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### Positive lookahead

Or you can use a positive lookahead like this:

```
,(?={)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### Positive both lookarounds

You can even use both:

```
(?<=}),(?={)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### Any positive of both lookarounds

And in case you want... you can use any of them:

```
(?<=}),|,(?={)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### Java code

So, you can use any regex you want in a code like this:

```
String regex = "<choose whatever regex you want>";
String[] t = s.split(regex);
```